# How to run two @test annotations parallel in two machines?

Tags: selenium

I have two @Test annotations and i want to run them in parallel one in machine1 and one in machine2 using TestNG.

For that i am using a testing.xml file which contains the below code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="TestSuite" verbose="3">
  <test name="DriverScript" parallel="methods" thread-count="2">
    <classes>
      <class name="testscripts.DriverScript"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

When i am running in two different machines it is not running in parallel..it is running one by one...is there anything that i missed here?

Note: DriverScript is the class name where i have two test annotations which needs to be run in parallel...

Thanks,

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/BjcRFIXNqgE

Comment: went through that link still browsers are opening in sequential

Answer (score 0):

You could swap this to threading and kick off both at the same time.

c# example:

```
    Parallel.Invoke(
        () => { //Test call goes here with parameters. },
        () => { //Test call goes here with parameters. }
    );
```

Of course this would be custom code and not relying on the TestNG framework specifically, but it would work and provide you control.